# Exe can't write in a XML file in the installation folder

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, exe

First of all I have to precise that I am Web developer. But face to a problem I was obliged to create an exe in WPF as simple it can sound with small datas stored in a `XML file`. 
The problem came after installation. I followed the rules but my WPF can't write in the XML file. I see that is permission because when I put all the folder installation in let's say D drive. I don't have any problem writing in the XML file. 
So How can I write in the XML file after installation in any client machine? Have I to add some instructions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Windows 7, the default user has no administrative rights. So applications are not allowed to write in programs directory (c:\Programs\myApp), cause they are executed with user rights as default. 
Application data should be stored in users directory (e.g. c:\user\fred\AppData\Local).

You can get the directory easy be using the [Environment.SpecialFolder-Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't save to Program Files on windows 7+. Instead you can create a folder in the AppData area. I use this to get an application directory

```
public static string GetAppDataDir(string company, string appName)
{
   string appDataDir = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables( "%APPDATA%" );
   string appDir = Path.Combine( appDataDir, company );
   appDir = Path.Combine( appDir, appName );

   if (!Directory.Exists(appDir))
      Directory.Create(appDir);
   return appDir;
}
```

Comment: It's not windows 7+ it's always been that way for non administrator users, it is just starting with Vista apps don't run as administrator as default.

Comment: In my case I have to provide the folder I think in configuration if the installer. I van see that I can use your method to read in the file but how to provide the path while installing in VS2013.

Comment: @Scott: The difference: Since Windows 7 the default user right has changed. In Windows XP you first user becomes administrator and most people dont create another one.

Comment: @Inanikian That's a different question. What I do on some projects is install the default file in same folder as the application. When your application starts it looks for the file in the folder returned by `GetAppDataDir` if it doesn't exist copy the one in the application folder. All changes are save to the copy. The advantage of this is you can always restore the default file.